# Proof that projective representations are given by unitary representations of the covering group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for resources or places where where I can see a proof of that. I have read Loring W Tu books on manifolds and differential geometry respectively and I know of Hall book on Lie GRoups but I am looking for something that is still accessible but covers abstract groups not just subsets of $\mathfrak{R}^n$

Comment: Not every projective representation will lift to a unitary one. Are you implicitly assuming the group is compact or do you mean it must lift to a standard representation?

Comment: I was looking for a simplified version of Bargmann's theorem that can be used for the Poincare and Galilei Group

Comment: Ah I think that is in the realm of infinite dimensional representations where I am less familiar. Over finite dimensions the Poincaré group doesn't have any unitary representations of course since it is non-compact